# AndEnginePhysicsBox2dExtension physics body over sensitive collision detector

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I'm writing an android app using the Andengine and AndenginePhysicsBox2dExtension.

I create two sprites that I overlay. One is a rectangle and another is a sphere. I attached a box body to the rectangle and a circle body to spherical shape. I have a collision detector on both and listen for when my player object runs into it. The problem is the CircleBody doesn't fit perfectly around the Spherical sprite, so I'm getting false positives for collision. Is there a way to reign in the perimeter of the circle body?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use PhysicsEditor tool for making bodies.It helps in making bodies that will fill to  your sprites.Following is the link for that tool:  http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor